# changing location of mapbox wordmark and text atribution

Tags: mapbox-ios

Rotating the map according to the device orientation, makes position of watermark a bit strange. I understand that that watermark and text attribution are placed relatively to the margin
[screenshot of landscape view of map on iphone X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nwuyr.png)
I would prefer to locate these objects closer to the corners [screenshot of portrait app view with mapbox wordmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6DQ.png)
How can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to set the logoView and the attributionButton margins to different values when the device is rotated, you need to access the [MGLOrnamentPosition](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.8.0/Enums/MGLOrnamentPosition.html) enumeration using the following code:

```
 if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
     mapView.logoViewMargins = CGPoint()
     mapView.attributionButtonMargins = CGPoint()
 }
```

where CGPoint would reference the appropriate x and y values for your device.